# How to create a bar chart from .txt file data using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

We have a text file data as follows:

Positive : 20

Negative : 10

Neutral : 30

Positive, Negative, Neutral are the labels and 20, 10, 30 are the count. my requirement is to draw a bar chart for the above data. X-axis should be lables, and Y-axis should be the count.
So can you tell me how to do this using matplotlib in python.

I have tried this code but getting some error

```
f=open('/var/www/html/form/tweetcount.txt','r')

line = (f.next() for i in range(4))
pieces = (lin.split(':') for lin in line)

labels,values = zip(*pieces)

N=len(values)

ind = arange(N)

plt.bar(ind,labels)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) There are two parts to this problem: reading in the text file and making the bar plot. The latter is done by calling `plt.bar` and then setting the labels.

Comment: modify this example to suit your requirements  http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html

Comment: I have edited my post with code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem was that you were trying to plot the wrong values.

This code should do what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Collect the data from the file, ignore empty lines
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip().split(': ') for line in f if len(line) > 1]

labels, y = zip(*lines)

# Generate indexes
ind = np.arange(len(labels))

# Convert the y values from str to int
y = map(int, y)

plt.figure()
plt.bar(ind, y, align='center')
plt.xticks(ind, labels)
plt.show()
```

You can see the final result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8bi3.png).